# Will doing a hard reset to an old commit on new branch will reset the master as well?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-reset

I want to see what the design looked like at a previous commit so I want to checkout to a new branch and then revert/hard reset to that older commit.

I am quite new to commit and wouldn't like to break anything by randomly experimenting so will hard resetting to an older commit on a new branch will hard reset the master branch as well to that previous commit.

I would like the answer to the above question as well as the correct way of doing this(for git beginners).

Thanks
dk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I dive into the below (which you should read and learn about because you will need it eventually), I want to mention that you can do this a much easier way, with `git checkout -b <commit-id>`.  This has the effect of checking out an existing (older) commit and making a *new* branch name that points to that commit.  It's like doing the `git branch` and then the `git checkout` and then the `git reset` below, all in one step.

## Using `git reset`

What `git reset` does is a little bit hard to explain, but easy to illustrate, especially if we have colors ... which we don't.  So, let's do this in multiple parts instead.

#### Drawing the DAG

First, we have the actual set of commits inside the repository.  These commits form a graph—specifically a **D**irected **A**cyclic **G**raph or DAG, though right now all we need is the name, and "DAG" is a [nice short name](http://www.biography.com/people/groups/famous-named-dag).  The main thing to know here is that each commit "points to" its parent commit(s), and these commits are quite solid and permanent.  No matter what else we do, these commits will remain in the graph, at least for some time.  We'll get to the exception (the "some time" part) later.

If we draw this with earlier commits towards the left and later (newer) ones towards the right, it looks something like this:

```
       o <- o
      /
o <- o
      \
       o <- o
```

(the slash `/` is standing in for a down-and-left arrow, which is not available in all fonts; the backslash `\` stands in for an up-and-left arrow).  Each `o` node represents a commit and the arrows represent the parent pointers.  This particular graph has six commits and no merges.

Each of these commits has a unique SHA-1 hash name, like `a123456...`.  Those names never change: each name is specific to its one particular commit.  You can use these names any time, but of course they are difficult to enter.  (Sometimes I use the mouse to copy-and-paste these long strings of numbers.)

#### Labeling the DAG

Since we know that earlier commits are leftward and later ones are rightward and commits point to their parents, I normally draw this more compactly.  Also, we would generally like to know which branches these commits are on, so let's add some branch names:

```
      master
        |
        v

     o--o
    /
o--o
    \
     o--o

        ^
        |
     develop
```

This is the same six commits, but now we know which branches they're on: the first two commits—at the left, and in the middle vertically—are on *both* branches, then there are two commits that are only on `master` (along the top) and two commits that are only on `develop` (on the bottom).  Note that the branch names point to the *tip-most commit* here.

#### Moving branch names around

The next thing to know about branch labels is that they *move*.  The commits are solid and permanent, but the labels are like little birds, flitting from commit to commit.  Let's make the graph a little bit bigger by adding one more commit to `develop`, and see what happens to the label:

```
      master
        |
        v

     o--o
    /
o--o
    \
     o--o--o

           ^
           |
        develop
```

There we go: it moved!  It still points to the tip commit, but that tip commit is the one we just added.

#### Adding new labels (new branches)

Now let's add a *new* label—a new branch—to this graph.  I'll point the new label to the tip of `develop` as well.  To make room, I'll draw the existing labels to the right, instead of above and underneath, but remember that these are the moveable labels.

```
     o--o      <-- master
    /
o--o
    \
     o--o--o   <-- develop

           ^
           |
          new
```

#### Using `git reset`

Now, assuming I have done `git checkout new` so that I'm on branch `new`, let's see what `git reset` does to the label.  Specifically, let's take an old commit and get its number, e.g., `fdeee3df9f54372c31506eb24f2b7f2339ba21ec` (this particular number is Git release 2.8.1):

```
$ git branch new
$ git checkout new
Switched to branch 'new'
$ git reset --hard fdeee3df9f54372c31506eb24f2b7f2339ba21ec
HEAD is now at d95553a Git 2.8.1
```

The graph for the repository for Git itself is much too big to draw, but suppose I did this in a smaller repository like the one that now has just seven commits (of course the hash would no longer be `fdeee3d...`).  Then I might now have this:

```
     o--o      <-- master
    /
o--o
    \
     o--o--o   <-- develop

     ^
     |
    new
```

(assuming I have given Git the right hash).  If I give Git the hash of the very first commit in the repository, I get this:

```
     o--o      <-- master
    /
o--o
    \
^    o--o--o   <-- develop
|
new
```

#### `git reset` moves the branch label

The point here is that what `git reset` is doing is *moving the branch label*.

Since I'm on branch `new`, the label that `git reset` moves is `new`.

#### Be a little bit careful with `git reset`

What if I were to `git checkout develop` now, though, and `git reset` it to point back one step?  That is, say I made the graph look like this:

```
     o--o      <-- master
    /
o--o
    \
^    o--o--o
|       ^
new  develop
```

Notice how there's no longer any arrow pointing to what used to be the tip-most commit of branch `develop`?

When this happens, that commit is now "abandoned" or "unprotected" (the more precise term is *unreferenced*).<sup>1</sup>  An unprotected commit becomes eligible for *garbage collection*.  The `git gc` command (which is invoked automatically for you as needed, so you don't normally ever have to run it) will find these abandoned leftovers and recycle them to get your disk space back.

Eventually, then, after `git reset`-ing away the extra commit on `develop`, Git will really remove it, and we'll have this:

```
     o--o      <-- master
    /
o--o
    \
^    o--o
|       ^
new  develop
```

That is, we'll be back to just the six commits.

A branch name protects the tip commit of its branch, of course—but it also protects all the commits that are *not* at the tip, because in Git, we can always follow the arrows, and commits point back (leftward, in these drawings) to their parent commits.  Any commit we can reach by starting with a name, following an arrow to a commit, and following the commits' arrows to other commits—all those commits are *reachable* and therefore protected and remain in the DAG forever.

You must therefore be at least a little bit careful with `git reset`, to make sure you have *some* label—some branch name, usually—still pointing to the commits you want to keep.  Making a *new* branch name, and moving that around, guarantees that you're OK.

#### Be more careful with `git reset --hard`

While *all* `git reset`s move branch labels, the `--hard` reset does something else too: it erases work in your index/staging-area and in your work-tree, by resetting those to the *same* commit to which you're having `git reset` move the branch label.  Often enough, as in your case, this is just what you want anyway.

In fact, sometimes you *don't* want to move the branch label, but you *do* want to reset your index and work-tree.  In this case, you can just run `git reset --hard` without naming a specific commit.  Git will "move" the branch label from its old commit to ... wherever it is now.  That is, it actually stays right where it is.  Then Git will go on to reset the index and work-tree, i.e., wipe out whatever changes you have.  If you were working on the code for a while and have decided to start over, this is what you want: "set everything back to the way it is in the most recent commit."  Using `git reset --hard` will do that.  It still moves the branch label, but moving it *from* where it is, *to* where it is, means that you only *see* the "reset the index and work-tree" effect.

---

<sup>1</sup>Fortunately, Git normally keeps every normal commit semi-protected for at least 30 days, using what Git calls *reflogs*.  Each branch has its own reflog, and there's one big reflog for `HEAD` as well, and these remember commit IDs for 30 to 90 days by default.  As long as the reflog is remembering—*referencing*—the commit ID, the commit is protected from garbage collection.

Comment: Whoa, that takes some typing, hats off to you. Could you pls take a look at this question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38372745/design-goes-awry-after-checkout-to-earlier-commit-on-popping-stash]

Answer (score 1):

> so I want to checkout to a new branch and then revert/hard reset to that older commit.

Actually, I think you want to do this in the opposite order, namely:

- checking out the earlier commit via `git checkout <SHA-1 hash of earlier commit>`
- checking out a new branch from there via `git checkout -b new_branch`

When you checkout the branch at the earlier commit, you will be in a detached `HEAD` state.  Creating a new branch from there should leave you with what you want.

Comment: Okay, I will try that. I would also like to know the answer to my question? Can you pls answer that ? this will help understand git better.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with checking out an old commit and creating a branch from that point AFAIK.

Comment: Ok, I tried what you said by checking out to second last commit but git shows: `error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        css/.sass-cache/bacc3ae0ceb52dd23ae7e6fc6d3812f0ace1bc3c/base.scssc
        css/base.css
        css/base.css.map
        css/base.scss
        elements/footer.php
        elements/header.php
        index.php
        js/custom.js
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting`

Comment: You have changes to certain files on your branch at the `HEAD` commit.  What does `git status` show you?

Comment: When I checkout to the last commit it shows `$ git checkout 63f5522
M       css/.sass-cache/bacc3ae0ceb52dd23ae7e6fc6d3812f0ace1bc3c/base.scssc
M       css/base.css
..M       js/custom.js
D       slides/banenr-img1.jpg
Note: checking out '63f5522'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state....
If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. HEAD is now at 63f5522...` Why there is diff in checking out to last & second last commit ?

Comment: Yes, this message is basically telling you what my answer says.  What does `git status` show you from the `HEAD` of your branch?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117233/discussion-between-dkjain-and-tim-biegeleisen).