# Design goes awry, after checkout to earlier commit on popping stash

Tags: git, git-stash, git-checkout

My design (html/css) changed/gone awry after I popped back stashed repo.

Here is what I did. In order to temporary try out something,

1. I did a `git stash`
2. Then, checked onto an earlier commit `git checkout fd3243d` but did not make any changes.
3. Immediately did `git stash pop`.

Now, to my horror (that sinking feeling), when I refreshed design in browser it went totally awry and on the very top it reads

`<<<<<<< Updated upstream ======= >>>>>>> Stashed changes <<<<<<< Updated upstream ======= >>>>>>> Stashed changes`

Can anybuddy help me get back to the state pre first step i.e. before I did a `git stash`?

I don't have any backup's and last commit was done quite a while back. I have a feeling that this can be done but don't know how since I am very new to git.

Can anybuddy help?
Thanks
dk

Comment: Sounds sticky, and I wish I could help you now, but I'm afraid you might have to manually resolve the conflicts or ditch your changes. Next time use `git stash apply` so you retain your changes on the stack, then you can `git stash drop` when you're sure you're done with them. This would allow you to easily `git reset --hard`

Comment: Good news: It appears that doing `git stash pop` does _not_ change the stash in case conflicts occur, q.v. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22207256/undo-git-stash-pop-that-results-in-merge-conflict).  Check your stash to see if you work is still there.  If so, just checkout to the right place and pop again my friend.

Comment: Would you mind commenting or accepting the provided answer?

Comment: Hi, I have deleted that directory because I had a backup. However, after learning more abt `git`, I am 98% sure that your solution will quite likely solve that problem I was facing, so I will mark that as correct. Thanks for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you were on the **master** branch before follow these steps:

- Check that your stashed changes are still in the stash.
  *Git won't pop (remove) a stash that could not be applied cleanly*

  ```
  git stash list
  ```

  For more detailed checks try:

  ```
  git stash show stash@{<the-number-behind-your-stash>}
  ```
- This should be the case *(otherwise an edit to this answer will explain how to rescue your changes)*
- `git reset --hard` back to **master** (or any other branch that your stash was created from). You can find out from which branch (or commit) your stash was created by looking at the output from `git stash list` again
- `git stash pop` should now apply your changes cleanly and your changes are back